# track all user's activity using cookie with php

Tags: php, cookies, user-tracking

Here is the idea for keep track of a user in an online-shopping website:

1 - When a user comes in for the first time, I'll create a random hash and I'll send this hash through a cookie to the user and simultaneously I'll create a user with this hash in my Users table.

In that table I will store many users data like: (and I use mongodb by the way)

```
      * User page visit
      * User choose products (means user cart in my shopping cart)
      * User last login 
      and ....
```

2- When the same user comes again (say a day later), he will send that cookie (hash id) and I'll search into my database for that id and retrieve any data I want (e.g shopping-cart info).

I think this works fine and is a good way track the user (Do you agree on this?)

**Problem** :

What if a user cleans his browser history?

How do sites like youtube save our data (favourites and .... ) and even if I clear my browser or use another ip they had my favorites ready for me without logging into my account?

Answer (score -2):

**youtube**-like sites store each and every details about the user interactions. For showing your favorites, your likes and other things it saves the data on the server. Whenever the user logs in, the users data will be shown. If you want to implement this, then it is better to go for cloud computing to manage data efficiently.

Comment: cloud computing ? tracking users activity / ? 
what do you mean ?

Comment: it means moving your site to the cloud server , so that it efficiently handle the requests .